# Need to clone layer in OL3

Tags: javascript, clone, openlayers-3

How can I clone a layer in OL3 ?

For the moment I try this but it's giving me a different object with different aspect of a real ol.layer. Like you can see with inside console log I lost the instance of the layer and it's important for me to keep it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
      console.log("map layer is an instanceof ol.layer.tile? ", map.getLayers().getArray()[0] instanceof ol.layer.Tile)
      
      function cloneLayer() {
         map.getLayers().getArray().forEach(function(layer) {
            var copyLayer = jQuery.extend(true, {}, layer);
            console.log("CopyLayer is an instanceof ol.layer.tile? ", copyLayer instanceof ol.layer.Tile)
            console.log("CopyLayer is equal to mapLayer? ", map.getLayers().getArray()[0] == copyLayer)
         });
      }
      
      cloneLayer()

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. If you provide us more code, we may be able to help you in a better way

Comment: I add a plunker. You will see that it's not equivalent and I lost the instance of the layer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to find a situation that you will need clone a layer and i don't find it.

Many other classes in ol3 has their method `clone` to do it. Clonning a layer involve copy your source, that has features and many many many other objects.

The jQuery.extend work's fine for DOM elements, it was made to DOM objects, [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), for complex objects that are instances of custom classes, prototyped classes, like all ol classes are made off, clone an object is much more complex than iterate its properties and copy each one.

So, i suggest that you create a new layer and just copy their options, if you need another layer with same characteristics.

Or, if you could explain the situation that you need to clone a layer, maybe we can have an alternative solution.

Comment: May be your right, I will analyze my approach and give more details later. Thanks

Comment: Finally there is no more need for me to clone layer and it's probably a bad approach to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familliar with OL3 but maybe you could try to use your original object as the prototype of the new one with

> var copyLayer = Object.create(layer.prototype)

Comment: You need to pass the layer prototype instead of layer itself.
that will not clone the layer properties to copyLayer.

see [specification of Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)